# including the content from 2 activities in 1 activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activities (lets call their layouts activity_one and activity_two). Both with seperate XML templates and seperate Activities.

in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of one of them I am calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);`

One of the subviews in this layout is a LinearLayout. I want to put the content of R.layout.activity_two within this LinearLayout and if possible use the code from its activity class (the onClickListeners etc).

The reason I want to do this is that the Tablet version of the app I am building should show data from both views.

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use fragments for that, with fragments you will be able to have two separate layout files, two separate fragments - which will be quite similar to your current activities (its quite easy to convert activity to fragment), and also you will need additional activity that will include in itself those two fragments.

You can still have your current activities showing their layouts, just create FragmentActivity for each such activity, and show apropriate fragment.

Other solution might be with using layout include tag, that allows to include one layout into another.

btw. fragments were introduced to make it easier to build tablet versions (big screen) of application, while still being able to show UI version for phones (smaller screen).

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way here i just gave simple demo

**activity_one.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnActivityOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activity One"/>

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/activity_two"/>

</LinearLayout>

**activity_two.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnActivityTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activity Two"/>
</LinearLayout>

**MyActivity.java**
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btnActivityOne;
    private  Button btnActivityTwo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);
        btnActivityOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActivityOne);
        btnActivityTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActivityTwo);

        btnActivityOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"Activity One Button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnActivityTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,"Activity Two Button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: No need to copy the whole code for that activity just use the <include> tag for that

Answer (score 0):

Simple work using actvities itself

For your first question

`content of R.layout.activity_two within your LinearLayout`

Use the `<include ../>` tag for that

Eg: `<include layout="@layout/activity_two" />` within your `LinearLayout`

For your Second Question

`if possible use the code from its activity class (the onClickListeners etc).`

Make a class `Extends Activity` and add all the listeners you need in common and name the class as `BaseActivity` and extend BaseAcitivity instead of Activity for your 2 Activities.